# Developing Paho-Mqtt-C Application on Host for Target having libraries

Tags: c, arm, cross-compiling, yocto, openembedded

Basically, I have the paho-mqtt-c library installed in my rootfs using Yocto build environment. Since it was already included in meta-oe layer, I simply had to add that recipe to IMAGE_INSTALL_append variable.

I confirmed this by checking the following:

```
root@am65xx-evm:/usr/lib# ls | grep mqtt
libpaho-mqtt3a.so.1
libpaho-mqtt3a.so.1.0
libpaho-mqtt3as.so.1
libpaho-mqtt3as.so.1.0
libpaho-mqtt3c.so.1
libpaho-mqtt3c.so.1.0
libpaho-mqtt3cs.so.1
libpaho-mqtt3cs.so.1.0
```

Being a novice with building cross-compiled applications and setting up tool chains, I have a basic question which I couldn't exactly find an answer for.

Now that my target machine has the library installed, how to I develop an application on my host machine running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

I can do apt-get install and get the same library, but using the cross compiler to compile the C file, it is not able to see the the MQTT Library.

For example:

```
~/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc mqtt-test.c -l paho-mqtt3c
mqtt-test.c:4:10: fatal error: MQTTClient.h: No such file or directory
 #include "MQTTClient.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: where have you placed such a header file? Is it in the same folder as your source code (the one you're trying to compile) is? Is it in a standalone folder? I think that this is a include path issue...

Comment: You need to create a Yocto SDK with bitbake <image> -c populate_sdk and use it to cross-compile your applications, see [manual](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#sdk-building-an-sdk-installer). SDK adds default packages for an image, but you could need to add some packages, see [this section](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#sdk-adding-individual-packages).

Comment: @Nayfe Sadly Processor SDK provided by TI doesn't support populate_sdk.
The compiler I am using also doesn't seem to have the -l flag if I see the options via --help.
Do you think I should write my own recipe for this? If so, is there an example recipe I can refer to for cross-compiling applications.
I assume I would set the DEPENDS = "paho-mqtt-c" in this recipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
LICENSE = "GPLv2"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://COPYING;md5=b234ee4d69f5fce4486a80fdaf4a4263"

SRC_URI = "file://mqtt-test.c \
           file://COPYING"

S = "${WORKDIR}"
TARGET_CC_ARCH += "${LDFLAGS}"

DEPENDS = "paho-mqtt-c"

do_compile() {
    ${CC} mqtt-test.c -o mqtt-test ${CFLAGS} -lpaho-mqtt3c
}

do_install() {
    install -d ${D}${bindir}
    install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/mqtt-test ${D}${bindir}
}
```

This is the recipe I used with the following directory structure:
[image]

Ignore the lmbench and hello-world - they were a sample from TI's tutorial.

Notice the `DEPENDS = "paho-mqtt-c"`
Apparently the `-lpaho-mqtt3c` flag with the `do_compile()` seemed to work this time.

I still wonder why I could't simply invoke the Linaro compiler and compile this separately.